# Why is my answer displayed below others?

Tags: support, voting

I have posted one answer on Stack Overflow. Here it is: [problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015410/customize-android-intent-action-send).

My answer has 10 upvotes, which is higher than the other two answers, but my answer is displayed after all the other answers.

Why is that? How can I make it show above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're sorting by active posts and not by votes.

Simply click on the votes tab, and your answer will appear 2nd instead of 4th.

[image]